# Is it possible to synchronize postsrsd rewritten e-mail addresses to another postsrsd machine?

Tags: postfix

I would like to use two mailservers for loadbalancing/failover - so one receives an e-mail and rewrites e-mail address with postsrsd. Then response to that e-mail is received with second mail server and this server needs to know, what was the original rewritten address so he can send the response e-mail to it. But this information is only on first original mail server.

How can I synchronize (and merge) postsrsd "database" to another machine?

Is it sufficient to set same /etc/postsrsd.secret key on both machines and will it work?

Comment: Did you already sent out messages rewritten with different keys? If you did, you would want each server to check against each key, which is more than just using the same key for future signatures (postsrsd does support this).

Comment: At first, I didn't realize that original address can be reconstructured directly from "new" address and is checked with signing key, there is no database. So I can use same key or multiple keys, as written in readme of postsrsd - `Each line of /etc/postsrsd.secret is used as secret. The first secret is used for signing and verification, the others for verification only.` Thanks!